# gpointing-device-settings lost on reboot

Tags: mouse, mouse-scroll, trackpad

I've been using gpointing-device-settings to enable both two-finger and edge scrolling on my trackpad, but it seems to not "remember" after reboot. The settings are still "ticked" in gpointing-device-settings but two-finger scrolling doesn't work until I uncheck and recheck the tickboxes for two-finger scrolling. 
How can I get Ubuntu to remember after reboot that I want both two-finger and edge scrolling without having to open gpointing-device-settings each time?

Comment: Vote to close, because it's a bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/gpointing-device-settings/+bug/489830).

Comment: @htorque how kind :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In dconf-editor you can edit the settings like this:

Go to org/gnome/settings-daemon/peripherals/touchpad 
There you can select e.g. two finger scrolling instead of boarder scrolling, disable while typing, tap-to click and all the other nice usability-enhancing features.

Maybe it's not as nice as gpointing-device-settings, but if they are not able to keep their tool updated, just forget about it and use dconf-editor.

this seems to affect hundreds or thousands Linux Users from many distributions it seems. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gpointing-device-settings/+bug/489830

Comment: Hallelujah thank you. This is been killing me for months.

Answer (score 7):

Store your current settings:

`synclient -l | sed 's/Parameter settings://;s/ //g' > ~/.synpadSettings`

Recover them:

`cat ~/.synpadSettings | xargs synclient`

I'm sure there's a good place to put these as shutdown and startup scripts for the your X session.

Comment: This works on 14.04, good work, much better than the old way of switching to dconf-editor

Comment: You can use `1d;s/ //g` rather than `s/Parameter settings://;s/ //g`, but this is the best answer. Thanks!