# How to permanently disable touchpad in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, touchpad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable Touchpad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65951/how-to-disable-touchpad)

I'm looking for a way to permanently disable the touchpad in Ubuntu 12.04 (my computer is a Lenovo Thinkpad Edge on which it isn't possible to disable it in the BIOS).

I tried the applications GPointingDeviceSettings and synaptiks 0.8.1 as well as the applets touchpad-indicator and Jupiter. None of these does the trick of disabling the touchpad permanently.

Jupiter comes closest - it remembers that I have disabled the touchpad after restart - but when I login after the computer has been in suspend mode, the touchpad is enabled again.

Can anyone help me in disabling the touchpad possibly at a lower level so it won't in any way be enabled unless I choose to enable it?

I'm totally new to linux so a detailed explanation would be much appreciated ...

The links, so far, doesn't address my question. I have no problem turning the touchpad off and making it stay off after reboot but when I login after the computer has been in an altered power mode it's on again. Isn't there a way to permanently disable a device like touchpad?

Comment: Why would you want to permanently disable touchpad on laptop?

Comment: Possible answers to similar question http://askubuntu.com/questions/65951/how-to-disable-touchpad

Comment: I have disabled it in the BIOS.  That is permanent for any OS you choose to install.

Comment: @Flint I do  on mine because it is a horrible touchpad, and ends up getting touched accidentally while typing, etc, causing unwanted effects.

Answer (score 7):

I installed [Pointing Device](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gpointing-device-settings/) (package: `gpointing-device-settings`) from the store and it did disable my touchpad.

Answer (score 6):

The command

```
synclient TouchpadOff=1
```

is what I use (change 1 to 0 to re-enable).

Comment: This does not work for me (Thinkpad x230, Ubuntu 13.10). After setting TouchpadOff=0 the setting is reset to TouchpadOff=2 as soon as I touch the touchpad.

Comment: @AndreasJ. Same happened to me. As soon as I set `TouchpadOff=1`, it would change it to `TouchpadOff=0` and then to `TouchpadOff=1`. Very odd! I'm using Ubuntu 12 LTS, on a Latitude E6510...

Answer (score 3):

Here is what finally solved the problem (posted by myself):
[gpointing-device-settings lost on reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64334/gpointing-device-settings-lost-on-reboot)

What had me (a linux newbie) confused was the difference between gconf and dconf. In this regard this was helpfull:
[When to use gconf vs dconf?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91403/when-to-use-gconf-vs-dconf)

Comment: How do I flag this as the right answer (read somewhere that answering your own question - if you figure it out yourself - is recommended) ...

Comment: When you answer your own question, you can accept your own answer starting 2 days after posting it.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a tutorial with screenshots on how to disable your touchpad [here](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/02/disable-touchpad-while-typing-or.html).

There was an ask ubuntu article about this [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65951/how-to-disable-touchpad).

One reason you might want to disable your touchpad is because you have a mouse connected to the laptop, so do not need to use the touchpad. The touchpad sometimes accidentally gets used, moving your cursor around the screen to a place you don't want it to be.